# having trouble writing script for bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have to write a program in bash and I understand logically how to do it I just cant get in into code. The problem is this "Write a program called "multiply" to get two numbers from the user and calculate the first number times the second number and show the result.
You are only allowed to use loop and addition operator(+). You are not allowed to use (*)."

I get you have to add one number to the other number nth amount of times to get the "product" but I have no clue how.

Any help?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a "please do my homework" question. If you were to ask about specific concepts you don't understand, we could explain them to you, but you've just thrown out the entire question. If you're finding basic stuff like this difficult to wrap your brain around, you should find tutor. Having us do your homework for you won't help you pass the course.

Comment: bad thing is there is no tutor for this class or course and google isnt helping. Concepts aren't explained properly and I am not the only one that is clueless. I dont want the question answered, just a little guidance. Im already passing, but if this is "basic" than I hate to see what else is coming.

Comment: "no tutor for this class" - so you just turn up to the room and stare at the blackboard for half an hour and then leave? BTW - It is a good idea to do homework - it is a mechanism to learn things on your own - comes in useful later in life if you become a programmer

Comment: How can there be "no tutor"? There's nobody around who's ever taken the class before you? There are't any other students who understand the subject better than you?. You're right to ask for help, but you need to actually work with somebody who can help you focus on the problem.

Comment: Yeah is it hard to beleive there is no tutor? I'm not making this up. Things are not explained well in the class and there is no place you can go to get the help and everyone else in the class is clueless as well. If there was a group of students I knew that took this class I would ask them, but unfortunately I don't know who they are. I like to see code and break it down so I understand it that way I know next time. Im a Web guy not a programmer, and definetely not a bash programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Put this into a script.  Call it `multiply` and `chmod +x multiply` to make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the first value: " a
read -p "Enter the second value: " b
product=0
for (( i=0; i<b; i++ )); do
  ((product+=a))
done
echo $product
```

Here's an example running it:

```
bash-4.1$ multiply
Enter the first value: 8
Enter the second value: 7
56
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Im trying to breakdown the code and figure out what does what.

Comment: @user205200  To get you started, here are some references on the [for loop](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bash-for-loop-examples/), the builtin [read command](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html), and bash [expressions](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

in functional programming it would look like

```
multiply(a,0) -> 0;
multiply(a,b) -> a + multiply(a,b-1).
```

in bash it would look something like

```
#!/bin/bash
ANS=0
function multiply {
for i in `seq 0 $2`
ANS+=$1
}
echo ANS
```

Comment: -1 LOTS of errors here! It's impossible to believe you actually tried running this. 1. `for` loops require a `do` and `done` around the body of the loop. 2. You're looping one too many times.  That should be `seq 1 $2`.  3. `ANS+=$1` concatenates rather doing addition unless surrounded by `(( ... ))`. 4. The `multiply` function is never invoked. 5. `echo ANS` should be `echo $ANS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
SCALE=0;
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "Usage:   $0 <simple_math_problem>\n";
    printf "Example: $0 1+1\n";
else
    bc<<EOM
    scale=${SCALE};
    $@;
    quit;
EOM
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser / StackExchange.  Please read the question carefully before answering.  The question specifies that “You are only allowed to use loop and addition operator (+).  You are not allowed to use (*).”  It is unlikely that an answer that uses an external calculator program would be acceptable.